# AngularJS with asp.net webforms or MVC?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, webforms

We have an asp.net website running in our company. This website majorly use AJAX calls to interact with server and for that we have web methods in our code behind files.
Company is thinking to switch technology to Angular JS. I just want to know whether it is a good practice to use Angular JS with asp.net webforms or we have to convert from webforms to
asp.net MVC in order to switch to Angular JS? I have already read relevant questions but I need more specific answers, any one please put a light on this.

Answer (score 0):

As I look at it, it doesn't really matter what you use, because angularjs is implemented using only javascript and html code, and in both cases I don't think that implementing it in either asp or mvc will have any major impact, this does depend on your project size and complexity but for the most part I don't think you will face any problems.Then again this is just my viewpoint on this matter.